# Join multiple tables without duplicated results and without UNION in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, join, union

Lets assume we have two tables A and B in PostgreSQL:

#### A

| title | first_group_id | second_group_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| My Title | 1 | 2 |

#### B

| group_id | element_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | First |
| 1 | Second |
| 1 | Third |
| 2 | Fourth |
| 2 | Fifth |

I want to get the following result:

| A.title | B0.element_name | B1.element_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| My Title | First |  |
| My Title | Second |  |
| My Title | Third |  |
| My Title |  | Fourth |
| My Title |  | Fifth |

If I query something like the following - I will get 6 rows instead of 5 cause all rows from B0 will be mixed with all rows from B1 and the number of result rows will grow in progression if B0 or B1 have more rows:

```sql
SELECT A.title, B0.element_name, B1.element_name
LEFT JOIN B B0 ON A.first_group_id = B0.group_id
LEFT JOIN B B1 ON A.second_group_id = B1.group_id
FROM A;
```

| A.title | B0.element_name | B1.element_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| My Title | First | Fourth |
| My Title | First | Fifth |
| My Title | Second | Fourth |
| My Title | Second | Fifth |
| My Title | Third | Fourth |
| My Title | Third | Fifth |

I can achieve the desired behavior by using UNION but I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do that? Especially when it's required to make more than two JOINs in the same manner.

Comment: What's wrong with `UNION ALL`?

Comment: If there are 2+ joins it will be 2+ SELECT statements. I wonder, if I can achieve that is one SELECT statement which is definitely could be faster than executing 2+ different select statements.

Comment: I am not so certain that a `UNION ALL` will be slower than some other complicated SQL statement (at least it would be complicated for me).

Comment: Union all is the fastest way to cmbine two resultsets, as it doesn't check for doubles

Comment: The question needs refinement. Exact table definitions and requirements. Cardinalities for columns involved in the join. And always your version of Postgres. Should go without saying.

Answer (score 0):

**One neat option to avoid querying the tables twice is to unpivot `A` first.**

You need some `CASE` expressions because you also want to split out `element_name` back into different columns.

> Not so good at Postgres, I may have the syntax slightly off

```sql
SELECT
    A.title,
    CASE WHEN A.first_group_id  = v.group_id THEN B.element_name END AS element_name0,
    CASE WHEN A.second_group_id = v.group_id THEN B.element_name END AS element_name1
FROM A
INNER JOIN LATERAL (VALUES
    (A.first_group_id),
    (A.second_group_id)
) AS v(group_id)
LEFT JOIN B ON v.group_id = B.group_id;
```

Comment: There is no `CROSS APPLY` in Postgres (nor in standard SQL). You would be looking for a `LATERAL` join. But I don't think either is needed to the task.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a faster way. Works for your minimal demo:

```
SELECT a.title
     , CASE WHEN b.group_id = a.first_group_id  THEN b.element_name END AS first_group
     , CASE WHEN b.group_id = a.second_group_id THEN b.element_name END AS second_group
FROM   a, b;
```

Basically, join *once* to avoid duplication.

But your question leaves a lot of room for interpretation.
Chances are, you have additional constraints. This may be what you really need:

```
SELECT a.title
     , CASE WHEN b.group_id = a.first_group_id  THEN b.element_name END AS first_group
     , CASE WHEN b.group_id = a.second_group_id THEN b.element_name END AS second_group
FROM   a
LEFT   JOIN b ON b.group_id IN (a.first_group_id, a.second_group_id)
ORDER  BY a.title, b.group_id, element_name;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=90d765afae7b58328b472724d2912f3e)*

Plus, you might need an additional column to define order in table `B`.

And `UNION ALL` may still be faster, depending on undisclosed details.

---

The reason you get 6 rows with 2x `LEFT JOIN` in your example:

- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12464135/939860)

It's just the wrong approach for the task.

Comment: Downside is that this doesn't work properly if `first_group_id = second_group_id` which OP hasn't stated whether that is true or not